# Examples or documentation of the atlasvariables

Tags: qgis, atlas

Are there any examples or a documentation of the atlasexpressions??
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is displayed on the right when you select the function. It also comes with examples.

[image]

Comment: my gui was to small

Comment: @klausk Please upvote answers that help solve your problem.